# Book - Young girl trapped on alien planet, makes friends with a higher-up alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Can't remember all the exact details. Maybe someone can help me remember the title. It was about young woman who gets trapped on an alien planet, can't remember if she was separated from her family or not. She is left on the planet when she overhears plans she was not supposed to know about. She has nothing but the clothes on her back. On the planet are many types of different aliens, and they speak different languages. She ends up finding a way to support herself, and makes friends with an alien in a high-up position. There were many rules that she seems to continue breaking.

Maybe someone can remember the title of this book?

Comment: When did you read it? Was it in English? Were the aliens largely humanoid? Did she learn to speak those other languages? Do you remember anything of what those plans dealt with? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info provides a checklist of details you can give us to help us help you.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this? I suspect it could match a wide variety of works.

Answer (score 3):

**It's called *[Tin Star](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/17255996-tin-star)*,** a YA novel by Cecil Castellucci.

Tula gets trapped on a space station but she ends up surviving by bartering and trading. She wants to get revenge on Brother Blue for leaving her behind and beating her up. She also meets an alien who is always looking out for her, Tournour, who becomes a romantic interest.

I believe this is the YA novel you're looking for.

Comment: Can you provide a link to goodreads or something of the like?